# avoid multi touch on list view android 4.2.2

Tags: android, listview, multi-touch

I have a list view with five rows. If user taps on a row dialog corresponding to that row will open.

But when the user taps on two rows at a time using two fingers, two poppus are being opened.
Can someone please suggest how to avoid this behaviour.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try setting

`android:splitMotionEvents="false"`  attribute of your `ListView` from xml.

It may disable multi touch events.